# django test urls status code

Tags: python, django, testing

hello i create some test for my project mainly to enrich my knowledge.

and I have some questions.

simple test code :

test.py

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase
class User_Form_Test(TestCase):
    def test_logged_user_get_details(self):
        response = self.client.get('/details/', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_logged_user_get_details_images(self):
        response = self.client.get('/details-images/', follow=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^details/(?P<id>\d+)/$', views.details, name='details'),
url(r'^details-images/(?P<slug>[^\.]+)/$', views.details_images, name='details_images')
```

all this code work fine I take passed messages in this two test.

my question is how to can test like this example all possible regex from `id` in first case and second `slug` in second case automate ?

Answer (score 5):

First of all use path() and re_path(), I think url() is depreciated or even removed.
Looking at your regex pattern looks like you have made `id` and `slug` optional, which doesn't makes much sense, but its ok.
Now you want to check for all possible regex for `id` and `slug` but the total possible matches are infinite as any number will match `id` and anything will match `slug`, so its not possible.
I think for your first case in your views you will look for an object with that `id` in your database and then show details about it on the page you render. Therefore in your setUp() method you should create a few objects of your models, eg.:

```
def setUp(self):
    MyModel.objects.create(id=1)
    MyModel.objects.create(id=5)
    ...
```

Now in your test check for these id:

```
def test_logged_user_get_details(self):
    response = self.client.get(reverse('details', args=(1,)), follow=True)    # for first object
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
    response = self.client.get(reverse('details', args=(5,)), follow=True)    # for second object
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Also check for a id that doesn't exists:

```
response = self.client.get(reverse('details', args=(2,)), follow=True)    # for object that doesn't exists
self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 404)
```

Since name of test suggests only logged in user can access the given webpage so, your setup should contain this (assuming you are using django's auth):

```
self.user = User.objects.create_user('test', 'test@email.com', 'testtest')
```

Then in every test that requires login, first do this:

```
self.client.force_login(self.user)
```

As you said in your question you want to check for all possible regex matches which is not possible, but for some reason if you want to check for many `id` or `slug` you can use a loop:

```
for i in range(1,n):    # define n
    response = self.client.get(reverse('details', args=(i,)), follow=True)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

to me doing something like this makes no sense but since since I don't know completely about how your app works, it might be of some use to you.